# self-built node does not find the correct C libraries

Tags: node.js, gcc, environment-variables

I don't have root on my server, so I built a gcc in my working directory with the libs also installed somewhere there. It all went well when building node (7.9.4) with this gcc, until the `make install` finished. I tried to run `node -v` and there is an error produce:
`/standard/location/of/dynamic/libs/for/the/servers/gcc/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by ./node).`

So it seems like the node, although compiled and built with my own gcc, still resolves to the /usr/bin/gcc 's libraries when resolving.

Have I missed a flag while configuring? I only used --prefix and --without-snapshot, (not that I think the latter flag matters). Or are there environment variables like `NODE_PATH` that could do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the place where you have the libraries that you used to build your Node.

For more info see this:

- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: I tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` both before configuring and before running ./node, and it still doesn't work. Could it be that some other shared objects in other directories tried to link to libstdc++.so.6 internally? I'm sorry if I have neglected something from your link, but would it be possible if you could instruct me with some of the most common dirs used for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Thanks